# Why is flexbox centering not working in I.E 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, flexbox

I have the following simple animation **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1390a5n7/)**:

Now my question is pertaining to the flexbox centering code i have on the body element, I.E.

HTML:

```
 <body class="loading-doc">
    <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.loading-doc  {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #fff !important;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
            align-items:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
        -ms-flex-pack:center;
            justify-content:center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The above code centers the(only) child element of the body in all browsers, except in IE , can somebody explain why ?

I have tested in I.E. 9 , 10 , 11(which shows as edge in the browser tools even though i am on windows 8.1) , and flexbox just does't work, i'd expect atleast ie 11 to work , but it does't work, Why ?

caniuse.com **[LISTS](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)** ie 11 as supporting flexbox partially , the properties i have used are pritty basic flexbox properties so why are they not working in ie 11(which also supringly shows as edge in my ie console). Can somebody explain this to me ?

**EDIT::**

I am attaching a screenshot of what i am seeing below.

[image]

Look towards the center Right.

Comment: is postion:fixed; really needed here ?   have you tried display:inline-block ? ...

Comment: @GCyrillus its a "why" question not a "how to get it to work" question , so i'd really like to know , why this css is not working.

Comment: Your animation is centered the same in Chrome and IE11 on my PC. No difference.

Comment: your fiddle update without margin https://jsfiddle.net/1390a5n7/2/ flex is still buggy in IE ... but you know you did mention caniuse :)

Comment: @Michael_B hmmm interesting , well are u using edge ? or ie 11 also windows 8 or 10 ?

Comment: @Michael_B added screenshot .

Comment: Hi Alexander - your screenshot is not what I'm seeing at all. The animation (in your fiddle demo) is centered for in Chrome, IE11 and FF.

Comment: @Michael_B I'll leave this for now then , but i am sure this is some kind of a bug ! :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Do you see the same issue in the Fiddle you provided? Everything looks ok in IE11 when I try it.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes no, i see the issue on my system only , even micheal above says it works fine for him in IE - 11 , so i am unsure what's wrong here , but i am certain its an issue.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Hmm. Only thing that comes to mind is the `doctype`. What `doctype` are you using on your local copy?

Comment: `<!doctype html>`  thats it :)

Comment: Please try add property for that `min-width: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there is no issue with the code you have provided.  It works in all versions of IE, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc.  The issue, I believe, is in your own version of IE.  Try resetting IE to default settings (make a back up first to make sure you don't lose anything).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/923737

> Manually open the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box
>
> a.Close all Internet Explorer and Explorer windows that are currently
>   open. b.Start Internet Explorer.
>
> Note If you are running Windows 8.1 or Windows 8, start Internet
>   Explorer from the desktop. Changing your settings will affect both
>   Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer that you start from the
>   desktop. c.On the Tools menu, tap or click Internet options. If you
>   don't see the Tools menu, press Alt.  d.In the Internet Options
>   window, tap or click the Advanced tab.  e.Tap or click Reset. If
>   you're using Windows Internet Explorer 6, click Restore Default.
>
> 2.In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, tap or click Reset.
>
> Note Select the Delete personal settings check box if you also want to
>   remove browsing history, search providers, Accelerators, home pages,
>   Tracking Protection, and ActiveX Filtering data.
>   3.When Internet Explorer finishes applying the default settings, tap or click Close, and then tap or click OK. 
>   4.Exit and then start Internet Explorer.

This happened to me once a while ago where my IE wasn't showing the same thing as everyone else.  Lucky for me I only use IE for testing, so a reset wasn't going to ruin anything for me.  However, a reset worked perfect and fixed my issue.  Let me know if it fixes yours.

Comment: If this worked, you should mark this answer as correct so other people know it is resolved.